# Corruption of the heap & F12 Problem

Tags: c++, breakpoints, glut, heap-corruption

I'm trying to draw a line using GLUT with C++ - the IDE is VS 2008 -but an error message occurred :

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in
>   Graphics.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the
>   heap, which indicates a bug in
>   Graphics.exe or any of the DLLs it has
>   loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user
>   pressing F12 while Graphics.exe has
>   focus.
>
> The output window may have more
>   diagnostic information

of course I don't have any breakpoint in my code this is my code :

```
#include <glut.h>


void init (void)
{
 glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 gluOrtho2D(0.0,200.0,0.0,15.0);
}//end of the function init

void lineSegment(void)
{
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

 glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
 // D R A W  A     L I N E 
 glBegin(GL_LINES);

  glVertex2i(180,15);
  glVertex2i(10,145);

 glEnd();

 glFlush();
}//end of the function "lineSegment"
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 glutInit(&argc,argv);
 glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
 glutInitWindowPosition(50,100);
 glutInitWindowSize(400,300);
 glutCreateWindow("N.S"); 
 init();
 glutDisplayFunc(lineSegment);
 glutMainLoop();

}//end of the "Main" function
```

Anyone know the problem?

Comment: Well, did you push F12? Also, more exclamation marks doesn't make people answer any faster. :)

Comment: Yes I did ! and it  gave me that the problem in the  glutMainLoop() function ... but I don't know what's the wrong with it !!

Comment: What line did it break on? Did the stack or heap look corrupted?

Comment: It's in the header file of GLUT . the line is:
 
GLUTAPI void APIENTRY glutMainLoop(void);

Comment: Did you actually press F12? Does the problem go away if you don't press F12? The F12 key automatically breaks into the debugger on Windows - it has no effect if no debugger is attached.

Comment: Just, don't push the F12 key. That's like putting a breakpoint then saying "ah, I've stopped at a breakpoint!" F12 is just there as a utility. If you don't need to break, don't push F12.

Answer (score 6):

A little googling produced some results.  It looks like F12 is **reserved by the OS** when you are running in the debugger.  [Here is a good thread](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=561537) about the subject.  There is a *workaround* available from MSFT in [this connect article](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/106201/f12-stops-execution-while-debugging-and-sometimes-kills-windows).  This gist of it is that when a debugger is active, the OS responds to F12 by entering the debugger at exactly the line of code that is currently executing.

If you are not in a debugger, then this is probably a stack corruption problem.  Your code snippet looks pretty simple, but I do not know GL well enough to know if you are missing a required call or breaking some other procedural rule.

Comment: I've googled about the problem . It's a memory problem . 
What I know is that the function glutMainLoop() is to put the program in an infinte loop that checks input from devices like mouse  and displays the intial graphics . But my question is : Where the problem is .. my code is clear and the bug occured in the GLUT header? and actually I don't understand . Does  the F12 key could help me to solve the problem ..or just to find where  it is ?

Comment: @N.S.: if you've pressed F12 _and_ you are in the debugger, then it will act as if it hit a breakpoint.  If you did not press F12 or are not running within a debugger, then heap corruption is likely.  The fact that the current line is shown as `glutMainLoop()` just means that this is the active function.  If you do not compile with debugging symbols or link against a debug version of the library, then the debugger does not know where in the library the program counter is - it just knows that you called `glutMainLoop()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what D.Shawley's written: The F12 key is quite handy, once you know about it.

It's worth stressing that the F12 key is **only active while a debugger is attached** and this key acts normally when there's no debugger. Still, it's safer to avoid mapping the F12 shortcut to anything useful in your app, for those times when somebody needs to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error message when programming in visual studio in C, totally unrelated to the F12 key. For anyone else programming in C who found this post via Google - my error was caused by a dangling pointer I had in my code.

Check all of your "free" statements and make sure you don't have any pointers left that refer to the memory you are deallocating.